# 10.12.4 Apple Upgrade breaks LaTeX; Fixed?

Tags: mac, mactex

The 10.12.4 upgrade to Apple's Sierra apparently breaks LaTeX: see 
here ([TexShop not opening files after upgrade to Sierra 10.12.4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364458/texshop-not-opening-files-after-upgrade-to-sierra-10-12-4)) and here ([New laptop, OS 10.12.4, new installation of MacTex, can't open .tex files, can't compile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364383/new-laptop-os-10-12-4-new-installation-of-mactex-cant-open-tex-files-cant))

Does anyone know if Apple has fixed this issue?

EDIT: On April 17th, two weeks after Richard Koch (author of Texshop) stated that "Apple is aware of this bug" I asked in the "duplicate" question if Apple had fixed the bug. There was no response, and we're now one month down the road from Apple's learning of the problem.

The initial upgrade from El Capitan to Sierra did not create this issue; it was only reported in the two questions I cited and the thread I posted in as a consequence of the recent .4 upgrade.

There's no point in upgrading to *Sierra* .4 if it breaks LaTeX, so it's strange to say that it would be more helpful if I created a problem that I'm not interested in encountering.  There is no further news on tex.stackexchange as to whether the problem has been fixed. Who would want to experiment under these conditions?

Comment: Your write-up is not very clear. For starters, MacOS 10.12 is called *Sierra* -- not *El Capitan*. Second, I happen to run MacOS 10.12.4 on my laptop, and I haven't experienced any problems at all with MacTeX2016 when I performed the upgrade from 10.12.3 to 12.12.4 -- or, for that matter, when I upgraded last fall from from 10.11.5 to 10.12.1. Rather than referring to somebody else's postings, it would be more helpful if you reported specific problem with *your* computing setup.

Comment: If you read the linked duplicate, there is *no* problem in reality, just a minor inconvenience for *some users*, under *limited circumstances*, for *some documents*. The problem is easily solved if it arises, and most of us have never encountered it. All my Macs are currently running 10.12.4 and there are no problems.

Comment: Also, your description of the issue is simply incorrect. The problem is with Apple's PDFKit, which affects Preview and other PDF viewers that use it, such as TeXShop.  It does *not* 'break' LaTeX.  Of course if you don't want to risk updating, that's your choice.

Comment: Looking at the three threads the problem seemed more extensive than what you describe. EC/Sierra are already full of problems--bad connectivity, menus failing to populate, etc.--so my hope is that Apple fixed at least some of these. But I don't want to lose Texshop.

Comment: MacTeX and TeXShop will always have good backwards compatibility for the MacOS, at least 2 OS versions prior and sometimes more. So if you have no need to upgrade your OS, don't. If you get a new machine, you're stuck with the current OS, but as I said many of us are using it without noticeable problems. I'm a also TeXShop user.